# Bootstrap: How to correctly centre a 6 column DIV inside of a fluid container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am curious to know what is the proper way of centring a DIV (col-lg-6) inside of a fluid container (12 columns) using Bootstrap?

Here is a screenshot of my design mockup, which explains what I am trying to achieve: http://d.pr/i/1iBrP .

So far I've read on Bootstraps website that this sort of thing can be achieved by adding an offset class e.g.:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-3">Auto cargo</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it a correct way of doing it or is there a better (or preferable) way of achieving this task?

Also, what if the width of the DIV would be 7 columns, meaning that the number of columns on the side of the DIV would be different because 12 - 7 = 5 columns and 5 is not an even number?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The current scenario looks correct. I'd be curious to see if there's a framework solution for the odd-number column centering. I'm not aware of one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you have 7 columns you can't center it with pure Bootstrap, you can do it like this:

```
.col-center {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

<div class="col-md-7 col-center">
```

2. Your code is correct, but you don't need to set `col-xs-12` class (it will automaticaly set 12 columns on mobile without that class - `div width = 100%`.
3. You set `col-md-6` and `col-md-offset-3` for medium screen sizes, it means that it will be the same on large(`lg`) screens, if you want to reset it on large screen you have to do it like this (change column size and reset offset):

```
<h1 class="col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-0">Auto cargo</h1>
```

4. You shouldn't set this class on `h1` element, this is better way:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-3"> 
      <h1>Auto cargo</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks makshh for your reply, much appreciated. So this is how I've changed my code now:

`<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6 hidden-sm-up">
        <h1>Автомобильные<br> перевозки</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-3 hidden-xs">
        <h1>Автомобильные перевозки</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`

I've added the second <h1> with the same content because my first <h1> has a <br> tag for the mobile version where I want the heading to be shown on 2 lines.

Comment: Added centering solution for `col-md-7`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Although, may I ask you one more question with regards to the correct html markup, can you please have a look at this screenshot and see if this approach with adding divs is right? I used to add classes directly to the <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <p> elements etc, but you mentioned that it is best to wrap these elements in a separate div and give it all those classes (if I understood it correctly of course).

So here is a screenshot: http://d.pr/i/Gjyy . Just want to make sure I understood you correctly. Thanks.

Comment: 1 thing: you should always have 1 `col-` class on div because it has proper negative margins (-15px on the left and right). So you should have in third div: `<div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm-up>...</div>`. If you don't do that, your div will be 30px longer than others.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see, thank you very much.. Other than that everything seems to be fine, yes?

Comment: 1 more thing: I think it is good to have divs with only `col-` and `hidden-` classes. In this divs you have classes like `main-heading` or `indent-top`. It is better to use this markup: http://pastebin.com/ZhHuiXaY (because for example if you have `padding-left` on `heading-main` it will affect default `col-` classes margins which is not good)

Comment: Ok, great, thanks for the advice. In the end there will be soooo many DIVs in my html structure... but I guess it makes sense because it will make easier for another person to understand my HTML markup. By the way is there some sort of article or other resource which you would recommend to have a look into, in order to understand these little things better?

Comment: When I was starting, I watched a lot of videos from Lynda. https://www.lynda.com/Bootstrap-training-tutorials/1421-0.html

Comment: If you have more questions, open a chat. Too much comments.

Answer (score 2):

**[Edited answer]**

You can use the helper class `center-block` in a `div` which can be a `row`.

Here is the document about this helper class: [Center content blocks](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center)

```css
.container-fluid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-xs-7 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.text-center > .single {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-2">
      I'm not centered
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-3">
      I'm not centered
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row center-block">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-3">
      I'm not really centered
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-7 single">
      I'm really centered
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

EDIT:

I updated the snippet because `center-block` doesn't work in the example I gave.

So you can use `text-center`on the `row` and a custom class called `single` which uses `display: inline-block` and `float: none`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do those complex code, just use below code, this will work in all screen.

```html
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The difference in the provided code is that the div is 10 cols at the sm size and only shrinks to 6 cols for md and above; this answer restricts it to 6 cols for sm as well, which doesn't seem to be the OP's original intent